# How to use handler to wait?

Tags: android, view, handler, ondraw

I am trying to display a diagram composed of lines and I want to display it lines by lines making a pause. So I need to call my own onDraw method at precise interval time but I don't know how to do this.

I try this in a while loop which changes the values of "start" and "end" which are coordinates of the line.

```
  final Handler h1 = new Handler();
  h1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {public void run() {
      lineView.addLineToList(new Line(start, end));
      h1.postDelayed(this, 1000);
      lineView.invalidate();
      }
  }, 1000);
```

But all the lines are displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Handler postdelay is just postpone your command to another time (here, 1000ms) and it has no cycle to do it again. If you want to call one function in a period time, just use "Timer" like below:

```
long delay = 500;
long period = 1000;

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(yourFunction, delay, period);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't understand what do you mean by yourfunction, because i see in doc that Timer.schedule takes a timerTask

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error : 04-18 13:57:28.280 2398-2568/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.